# linear actuator rod extension

Tags: rod, actuator

I need to extend the rod of 700mm linear actuator by 45 cm as in the picture.
Is it safe ?
[image: rod extension]

Comment: The answer depends on the load, material and diameter of the extension rod, as well as, the speed at which the load is being moved. This possibly is a question for the physics site.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What does this actually move and what is the year/make/model of the vehicle it belongs to?